# ruby on rails 3.1 global exception handler

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm developing an app with Rails 3.1.2 but I can't find some documentation that works with errors / exception (like 404) on this version of rails.

i have tried things like:

In application controller

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,ActionController::RoutingError, 
             ActionController::UnknownController, ActionController::UnknownAction, :NoMethodError, :with => :handle_exception 

  def handle_exception 
   render :template => 'error_pages/error'
  end 

environment/development.rb

config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Where can I find a solution?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

In application controller

```
  class NotFound < StandardError; end
  rescue_from NotFound, :with => :handle_exception

  def handle_exception 
   render :template => 'error_pages/error'
  end
```

Comment: Just want to add: It seem to be invalid to use "End" instead of "end".

Answer (score 1):

Look at [action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb).

From the documentation in the source:

```
# This middleware rescues any exception returned by the application
# and wraps them in a format for the end user.
```

Short story short, it renders `ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions.render_exception` when the wrapped application (Rails, in your case), encounters an unrescued exception.

If you look through the default implementation, it ends up rendering something like `public/500.html`, which is what you see in the production environment. Overwrite the method or method chain it as you see fit to add your own implementation.